# How do I determine the last modification date of an ABPerson in iOS address book?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, abaddressbook

Can i get last modify date of ABPerson in iOS's Address book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer for my question. ABPerson have an property: const ABPropertyID kABPersonModificationDateProperty let we know Last modify date.